# Unable to add an element to a Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to add an element to the Numpy array. I'm doing something like this (putting in snippets of code, so please let me know if i'm missing some crucial info - and i'll add to it). I'd like someone to help explain what i'm doing wrong in the np.append function.

====================================

```
#Data type declaration for each element of array.
dt = [
    ('device', 'int64'),
    ('battery', 'u2'),
    ('version', 'f4'),
    ('ChargeStatus', 'u2'),
    ('temperature', 'u2'),
    ('time', 'datetime64'),
    ]

#dataArr is the final array and data is the individual element. 

dataArr = np.zeros(0, dtype=dt)
data = np.empty(1, dtype=dt)

<snip - code that reads a file, parses and writes into "data"> 

#The following line of code does NOT write any data into dataArr
np.append (dataArr, data)

#However, if i change the above line as below, dataArr gets the populated array i'm looking for. 

dataArr = np.append (dataArr, data)
```

Comment: Read the docs for `np.append`.

Comment: Try that `dtype` in `genfromtxt`

Answer (score 0):

dataArr = np.append(dataArr, data)

is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason i asked is because that doesn't seem to be how various tutorials/examples are citing the use of the append function. For example: http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/Numpy_Example_List.html#append.28.29

Comment: Those examples are in an interactive shell.  They show the array returned by the function.  They do not show the original array after the function.   But I discouage the use of `append`.  It's the cause of frequent confusion and misuse.

Comment: Thanks. What's recommended when I need to keep parsing a file and add relevant data to an array? How is it better accomplished?

Comment: `np.genfrontxt` builds a list of tuples, and creates the array once, at the end.